# Creating a link that acts like a POST request

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, post

I have a table of tasks that users can assign themselves to. There is an Assign button and when they click it, I would normally want to create a POST request, assign the task to the user, and redirect them to the task details page. Normally that's fine and I could do that with a button in a form, but they also want to be able to click that button and have the task details page open in a new tab.

So if they were on the main page and wanted to grab three of the tasks, they would want to be able to Ctrl + Click or middle click the button, have each of those pages load in a new tab, and be assigned to each one they clicked.

That leads me to believe I need to make it a link instead of a button? But then that means the request would be a GET request. Would anyone be able to give me a good idea on how I could accomplish this?

I'm using AngularJS 1.4, but even without Angular, I'd be curious to know how I should handle this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it to load a separate page for each task or just one separate page that consists of all the selected tasks?

Comment: It would be a separate page for each task. If you left click, you get assigned and redirected to the task details. But if you do something like Ctrl + Click, it does the same thing except opens the details page in that new tab or window, each time.

Answer (score 2):

You miss something really nice, in pure HTML. Forms (the common way of doing POST request, isn't it) can have a target attribute, as links do, so the result can be displayed on another tab/window. Here is a sample :

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get" target="_blank">
...
</form>
```

Here are the possible target values : _blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename

If you need your result page to be displayed in one place or one another, (multiple buttons i.e.) then this will be the good moment to use javascript, for editing this target property.

Comment: Wow, I actually didn't know it had a target attribute. I'll look into it, thanks!